# Retrieving User information via API/Programatically

Tags: api, code

Can some one please let me know how to obtain the following information for a user programmatically or via API: :

1. Token
2. Client_Id
3. Client_Secret

We need to do this through a secure connection. Does Salesforce provide SSL via the main domain.

Comment: programmatically from where ? Including more details, such as what you've already tried or what resources (documentation) you've already consulted usually leads to better answers. We do expect you've looked into this yourself already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Token, ClientId and ClientId lead to the assumption that you are referring to a connected app.

ClientId and Secret cant be retrieved programmatically. They must rather be stored locally in a configuration element such as custom setting or variable and be passed as part of the OAuth flow, which is described in great detail here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

which will give you the access token and refresh token.